# relationship order by parent date

Tags: relationships, orderby, entry-date, parent

I've a channel episodes with a single relationship to the channel shows.
I would like to order my shows by the date of the latest episode.

So i've got this so far (simplified):

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" channel="shows" orderby="?" sort="?"}
   <div class="show">
     <h2>{title}</h2>
     <div class="date_updated">
       {parents field="epi_show" channel="episode" limit="1" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
         {parents:entry_date format="%d/%m/%y"}
       {/parents}
     </div>
   </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What's the best way to order these entries by the episode date?

Or should i approach it by a totally other way?